# Send a channel alert using a slack bot over post request

Tags: slack

I used [this](https://api.slack.com/tutorials/slack-apps-hello-world) tutorial to create a Slack bot. Now I want that Slack Bot to send an alert to the channel. However, simply including @channel in the message doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, to escape a sequence use `<` and `>`.
Secondly, the `@` should be replaced with a `!`.

The format of the message should therefore be:
`<!channel> Hello World`

This will notify the channel with the message Hello World.

For more information see the [docs](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting#linking_to_channels_and_users) (particularly the sections on the use of `<` and `>` and Variables).